# How to add a scrollview in Touch Bar in Storyboard?

Tags: swift, macos-sierra, nstouchbar

I am adding a few buttons to the Touch Bar in storyboard, everything works fine except that I can only fit about 4 buttons in there (since the buttons contain both image and text) in my education app.

I would like to add a scrollview to contains all the buttons, but does not seem to be able to drag a ScrollView into the Touch Bar. What is the best way to have a scrollable set of buttons in Touch Bar?

[image: Touch Bar in Storyboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You firstly need to insert **Touch Bar View** which can then contian **NSScrollView**.

It should look like this:

[image]

Then the final output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Did you also need to set the size for the scroll view too?

Comment: Yes, because **NSScrollView** height is by default bigger then height of the **NSTouchBarItem** , also notice that **NSTouchBarItem** width is determined from **NSScrollView** width, so be carefull on that one, because when you set the bigger width that the empty space in **NSTouchBar**, your **NSTouchBarItem** cointaining yout **NSScrollView**  will be not displayed at all.