# Adding many buttons to Touch Bar

Tags: swift, macos, nstouchbar

Has anyone managed to add a lot of buttons to the TouchBar on the MacBook Pro in a horizontal style scroll view style?  Apparently `NSScrollView` is actually supported on the TouchBar

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40611303/how-to-add-a-scrollview-in-touch-bar-in-storyboard) looked promising from Roman Roba however I cant get NSTouchBarButton's accepted onto the scroll view, only standard ones so they don't inherit from it.   My set up is almost identical to the post:

[image]

Comment: Firstly, **NSTouchBarButton** class doesn't exists. Yet in object library there is **Touch Bar Button** which when you drop into TouchBar it's just NSButton inside of NSViewController which is inside of NSTouchBarItem. So I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: NSTouch BarButton does exist "An instance of the NSTouchBarItem class is called an item"  https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstouchbaritem?changes=latest_minor.  The problem is as described in the question

Comment: Opened your link, searching for **BarButton** is giving no results. I said that **class** NSTouchBarButton doesn't exist. What do you want to inherit from exactly? from NSTouchBarItem? "I cant get NSTouchBarButton's accepted onto the scroll view, only standard ones so they don't inherit from it" .. if you put just NSButton or **Touch Bar Button** you are still getting only NSButton, so I don't understand what do you want your button to be inherited from since it still the same thing.